# Configuración de AP tplink TL-WA901LD para conectarme hacia mi red interna desde la wi-fi

Tags: wifi, red

Tengo un tplink ap **TL-WA901LD** , y necesito conectar a la wi-fi unas cuantas laptops en un salón de reuniones, donde está el problema:

Tengo un solo rango en mi lan : 192.168.2.0/24, y está lleno practicamente, tenía el tplink **TL-WA901LD** con un ip de la  red interna (192.168.2.233), pero cuando activo la opción dhcp, me muestra un rango de ip de la subred interna que ya están en uso. Por ejemplo : del 192.168.2.100 - 192.168.2.150, este mencionado anteriormente es la disponibilidad para DHCP.

Necesito una forma de acceder a mi red lan desde la wi-fi con este dispositivo, o leo cualquier otra solución que puedan ofrecerme.

!!!MUCHAS GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO !!!!

Answer (score 0):

ese AP es muy básico, necesitas un AP **dualband** que te permita tener una subnet secundaria, primero que nada te recomiendo buscar en la configuración de tu AP alguna opción llamada "Lease time" que básicamente es el tiempo promedio que el servidor dhcp del AP le deja asignada una ip dinámica a un dipositivo, dices que ya están llenas las direcciones (`192.168.0.1/24 ->253` direcciones) si de verdad tienes `253` dispositivos a la vez conectados entonces ese AP va a *"quemarse"* por que su ancho de banda es de `450mbps` y no alcanza para un trafico simultáneo de una red tan saturada, mi recomendación es que busques un AP dual band gigabit (2.4ghz y 5ghz) eso te permitirá tener 2 subnets que van a estar nateadas y puedan convivir entre ellas (`192.168.0.13`  puede convivir con la subnet `192.168.1.21`)